# Oracle APEX Shuttle -extract id from selection

Tags: oracle-apex, shuttle

I need to get ID of selected item in shuttle LOV (left side) and return this ID to page item? Process shuld be dynamic, so when I change selection, ID in page item should change too.

I've tried by dynamic action - set value but I can't catch this ID. Any idea how to solve it?

APEX 19.1

Comment: A shuttle allows a multi select. Also, the "selected" values of a shuttle are in the right pane. It is unclear what behaviour you're looking for. Can you describe in more detail what it is you're trying to achieve ? Maybe explain the business scenario ?

Comment: I'm using shuttle for building process structures. I move subprocesses from left to right pane. In left pane I have a lot of subprocesses and I'd like to add some context information for them that help user to choose right subprocess. Subprocesses have many attributes and I can't use all of them in names of subprocesses. I'd like to do some kind of tooltip or some context region with additional information about attributes for one selected subprocess. I realize that in left pane is option for select many rows but the purpose for this tool is just give a quick hint for user.

Comment: For that I need to extract ID from selected subprocess in left pane or in case of many selected rows it can be colon separated value like ID:ID etc. So I'm looking for some advice what shuold I look for?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm **guessing** you want to know, what option the user just clicked on.

*Caviat: This does not work with multi-select. That would be a bit more complicated.*

So, what you need is the client-side state of the shuttle item. For that we will need a bit of javascript.

The left side of the shuttle has the id [item name]_LEFT. So if you called your shuttle "P1_SHUTTLE" that'd be "P1_SHUTTLE_LEFT".

This item has an attribute called `selectedOptions`.
This holds an HTMLCollection of all currently selected/highlighted elements and the amount (called length).
So using the EMP table as an example, `document.getElementById("P1_SHUTTLE_LEFT").selectedOptions` looks like this:

```
HTMLCollection { 0: option, 1: option, 2: option, length: 3 }
​0: <option value="KING">​
1: <option value="BLAKE">​
2: <option value="CLARK">
​length: 3
```

However since we are only looking at single select, we will only ever get the **first element** of that collection.

So to get the value of the first selected element we can use:
`document.getElementById("P1_SHUTTLE_LEFT").selectedOptions.item(0).value`

Now, create a Dynamic Action

- event type: Click
- Selection Type: Item(s)
- Item(s): P1_SHUTTLE

with "Set Value" for your desired Page Item.

- Set Type: Javascript expression
- JS expression: document.getElementById("P1_SHUTTLE_LEFT").selectedOptions.item(0).value

Remember, everything we did here was **client-side**. IF you want to do pl/sql stuff with it, you need to submit the page item.

---

Update: To prevent js errors when nothing is selected, you should define a Client-side Condition for the DA with following javascript Expression:

```
document.getElementById("P1_SHUTTLE_LEFT").selectedOptions.length>0
```

Please remember to substitute P1_SHUTTLE with whatever your shuttle is called.

Comment: Thanks for solution. it is exactly what I need, everything works but I get JavaScript Error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')? Any ideas what this error is?

Comment: Hmm, that error means, that there is no "Value" at item(0).
That could mean, you didn't select anything, so there's not item(0) or you got a typo somewhere (in that case it wouldn't work at all).
a quick fix, would be to define a client-side condition so it doesn't fire, when nothing is selected.
I'll update my answer.

Comment: I hurried up. Something is still wrong. After start every thing works fine but when I'm moving item from left pane to right error returns, because left pane loose selection. Any idea how to prevent it?

Comment: Error is valid only for duble click move from left to right. Moving items by buttons with arrow works fine.

Comment: Did you put the client-side condition like I updated in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I did. Previously the error appeared before the modal dialog with shuttle started. After updete the clinet-side condition, I can move items between left and right pane by arrows and It works perfect. The last issue is with moving items by double click. After start I can move few items by arrows but just after double click the same error is back. What's interesting is that the left panel loses selection both when moving items with the arrows and when double clicking, but now only double clicking generates this error with the value.